# django 3 tables queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I have 3 tables populated from my Postgresql legacy DB.
I was able to get some data from vlan table but I have a trouble getting all the data from 3 different tables and put them into a table I created in the picture. I have tried multiple querysets such as list(chain(nameOfTables..))
Can you please help me? I have attached the image of the table

For example,, if I want to select specific columns and DB from multiple table..

select vlans.name, vlans.vlan_id, gateways.vip, gateways.master, gateways.vhid, subnets.subnet, subnets.dhcp from vlans, subnets, gateways where vlans.vlan_id=2599 and subnets.vlan_id=vlans.vlan_id and gateways.vlan_id = vlans.vlan_id;

Models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Gateways(models.Model):
    vip = models.GenericIPAddressField(primary_key=True)
    vlan = models.ForeignKey('Vlans', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    master = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)
    backup = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)
    nat = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)
    vhid = models.IntegerField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'gateways'


class Subnets(models.Model):
    subnet = models.TextField(primary_key=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    vlan = models.ForeignKey('Vlans', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    dhcp = models.NullBooleanField()
    dhcp_start = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)
    dhcp_end = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)
    dns = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'subnets'


class Vlans(models.Model):
    vlan_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    allocated = models.NullBooleanField()
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'vlans'
```

Views.py

```
def niro_list(request):


gateways = Gateways.objects.all()
vlans = Vlans.objects.all()
subnets = Subnets.objects.all()



context = {
    'gateways': gateways,
    'vlans': vlans,
    'subnets': subnets,
}

return render(request, 'niro/niro_list.html', context)
```

niro_list.html

```
<div class="table-responsive-sm">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Type(Scenario)</th>
      <th scope="col">Interface</th>
      <th scope="col">Vlan ID</th>
      <th scope="col">RDP</th>
      <th scope="col">Network(CIDR)</th>
      <th scope="col">Nat IP</th>
      <th scope="col">DNS</th>
      <th scope="col">DHCP</th>
      <th scope="col">DHCP pool start</th>
      <th scope="col">DHCP pool end</th>
      <th scope="col">Master IP</th>
      <th scope="col">Backup IP</th>
      <th scope="col">VHID</th>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  {% for instance in vlans %}

    <tr  #id='items-table'>

      <th scope="row" class="checkbox-row"><input type="checkbox" name="item" /></th>
        <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
          <td class="item">{{ instance.name }}</td>
          <td class="item"></td>
          <td class="item">{{ instance.vlan_id }} </td>
          <td class="item"> </td>
          <td class="item"> </td>
          <td class="item"> </td>
          <td class="item"> </td>
          <td class="item"> </td>
          <td class="item"> </td>
          <td class="item"> </td>
          <td class="item"></td>
          <td class="item"> </td>
          <td class="item"></td>
          <td class="item"> </td>

{##}
{#        {% empty %}#}
{#            <td><p>No contetns</p></td>#}

    </tr>

    {% endfor %}


  </tbody>
</table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYIuV.png)

I was able to join them together but problem is it returns whole set of object...is there any way I can grab one value by value?

```
    vlan_query_results = Vlans.objects.select_related('vlan_id').values_list('name', 'gateways__vip', 'gateways__backup', 'gateways__master', 'gateways__nat', 'gateways__vhid', 'subnets__dhcp', 'subnets__dns').order_by('vlan_id')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to write SQL query (seems you do), you can just run the SQL yourself. Put something like this in your view:

```
from django.db import connections
with connections.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(your_sql_query)
    res=cursor.fetchall()
```

And add the SQL result to your template's context. Then in the context you can iterate over your result. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But If I wanted to update DB through my application later.. would it be a problem if I don't follow ORM and just use raw query?

Comment: `select` query will not cause any problem. However, if you perform an `update` query, make sure to re-fetch the python object from database, because the model instance is cached in memory and does not reflect changes you do using raw query.